# Bash script to assign some data from a file to variables

Tags: bash

I have a file (userbouquet.test.tv) with the following format:

```
#NAME 4.8E-Astra  
#SERVICE 1:64:5:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::PVU 12322 V 27500 5-6  
#DESCRIPTION PVU 12322 V 27500 5-6  
#SERVICE 1:0:1:64:1:5E:30B022:0:0:0:  
#SERVICE 1:0:1:190:1:5E:30B022:0:0:0:  
#SERVICE 1:64:6:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::PVU 12360 V 27500 5-6  
#DESCRIPTION PVU 12360 V 27500 5-6  
#SERVICE 1:0:1:258:1:5E:300000:0:0:0:
```

Could you help me with one script that reads each line and check if line begins with string #SERVICE.
If line begins with string #SERVICE then to assign the coresponding value (for example 1:64:5:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::) into a variable.

**EDiT 1:** only lines that begin with string #SERVICE and end with ":" (example #SERVICE 1:0:1:64:1:5E:30B022:0:0:0:)
The lines that begin with string #SERVICE but end with a text (comment) should also be ignored (example #SERVICE 1:64:5:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::PVU 12322 V 27500 5-6)

I managed to writte the following:

```
#!/bin/bash  
userbouquet="/etc/enigma2/userbouquet.test.tv"  
for (( i=1; i<=$(grep "" -c $userbouquet); i++ ))  
do   
#
# HELP ME HERE
#
wget -q -O - http://127.0.0.1/web/zap?sRef={variable}
#example wget -q -O - http://127.0.0.1/web/zap?sRef=1:64:5:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::
sleep 3s  
done
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the provided file and `userbouquet.test.tv`? The same file?

Comment: yes, that is the content of the userbouquet.test.tv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

userbouquet="/etc/enigma2/userbouquet.test.tv"

while read -u3 a b _; do
    if [[ $a == '#SERVICE' && $b == *: ]]; then
        wget -q -O - "http://127.0.0.1/web/zap?sRef=$b"
        sleep 3
    fi
done 3< "$userbouquet"
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it will contain `PVU` at the end of $b in some lines. I'm afraid it differs from the OP's desired example...

Comment: @tshiono He only needs lines starting with `#SERVICE`.

Comment: If he wants `PVU` excluded, he should mention.

Comment: Right. I just noticed the OP's description `for example 1:64:5:0:0:0:0:0:0:0::`. He/she can solve it according to your comment anyway.

Comment: Thank you, the script is ok. It's working. Regarding the lines that end with PVU (or other text) it seems that they must also be ignored because the variable it's not good (it contain data that can't be used, probably it just a descriptor for the ending comment). Could you please adjust the script? Thank you.

Comment: Script has been updated.

Comment: Working as requested. Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the lines in the input example provided end with whitespace, so the awk pattern contains `[[:space:]]*` between `:` and `$` (end of line).

```
#!/bin/bash
userbouquet="/etc/enigma2/userbouquet.test.tv"

for variable in $(awk '/#SERVICE.*:[[:space:]]*$/ {print $2}' $userbouquet); do
    wget -q -O - http://127.0.0.1/web/zap?sRef="$variable"
    sleep 3s  
done
```

Comment: Good call with awk but you should use quotes when expanding a variable and potential glob characters like `?` => `"http://127.0.0.1/web/zap?sRef=$variable"`

Comment: This script unfortunately is not working. It's stuck. I added line  `echo variable= $variable`   but there is still no output.